Sequence in which rate limiter, load balancer, api gateway and reverse proxy should be placed
while creating a high level design for the system in which order - rate limiter, load balancer, api gateway and reverse proxy should be placed?
I understand we may or may not use all these in one system but still these components have some overlapping functionalities due to which I am confused on this

As you correctly mentioned, it's very uncommon to find those components, individually, in the same system. Usually you have one component which fulfils all these roles (or a subset of them, depending on your needs).
For example, nginx is a load-balancer and reverse-proxy by default, and it also has rate-limiting capabilities that you can enable. You can also configure it to work as an API Gateway.
So you technically you use one component and enable different capabilities on it, or configure it to work in a certain way.
Also, if we think about an API Gateway, it's primary role is to route requests to the appropriate microservice. In Kubernetes for example, the gateway points  to a service that load balances the traffic to multiple pods which belong to the same microservice, so load balancing happens on multiple levels depending on the architecture and technology we use.
So the question has multiple nuances. I recommend you study each component individually and then compare them to see where they differ, where they're similar and always think about the context/use-case, because it really matters.
